# How do I prevent TortoiseGit asking me who to login as?

Tags: tortoisegit

Ok, firstly **I have set up SSH keys, I am not asked for a password, this is not another authentication question**!

But I am still asked the question: 'login as' in a dialog box each time I wish to pull or push my code. How can I make this go away?

[image]

Comment: I had not seen that specific question, however that is not the dialog I am presented with, I'll upload an image.

Comment: Does the URL you'r pulling/pushing include a username? e.g. git@hostname?

Comment: @MrTux Nope, it is a local git server so the URL is `servername:reponame`

Comment: Then add the usename to the URL ;), e.g. username@servername:reponame

Comment: @MrTux *facepalm* worked like a charm, not sure why I though a local server url was any different to a remote server URL...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose your SSH-style URL for pushing/pulling does not include the/your username.

Just add it to the URL: username@servername:reponame

For this go to TortoiseGit settings -> Git -> Remote, click on the remote, change the URL and click on "Add New/Save".

[image: TortoiseGit | Settings | Git | Remote | URL]

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Tortoisegit app
Do fresh install
Initial step give next --> until finish
Under start wizard step
In the drop-down list give OpenSSH option
Then --> finish
Now your Tortoise is not asking for

Comment: Hi @ImranGani - did you see there was already quite a good (and accepted by the OP) answer to the question (from 2015!!)?  Is there something new in your answer that theirs doesn't contain?

Comment: Yes - this is how you revert to using ~/.ssh/config, which is what you want in some circumstances.